# Monotouch - Popups over everything

Tags: xamarin.ios, popup, modal-dialog

On iPhone, in Xcode, I can show a popup view which overlays everything, including the Tab Bar, etc, by using code like this -

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:mySpecialView];
```

I'm trying to do the same in MonoTouch, and the code I'm using is this -

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.Window.AddSubview(mySpecialView);
```

...but this crashes. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not say how it crashed - but I assume you're having a `ModelNotImplementedException` while using the `Window` property since it's not implemented by default (and is meant for storyboard).

You can either implement it to return the `window` field of the (autogenerated) `AppDelegate` (AppDelegate.cs file) or expose the same variable as a (static) field.

E.g. the default generated code

```
UIWindow window;

public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController ();
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}
```

would become:

```
static UIWindow window;

public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController ();
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}

static public UIWindow Window {
    get { return window; }
}
```

Comment: That's it - thanks very much. I thought it would be something simple, it's just finding it!

Comment: Many thanks! Making it static and exposing through a property works great.