# Get reference to UINavigationController

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a rootcontroller pushed on a `UINavigationController`.
Inside that rootcontroller class, I can access the `UINavigationController` with `this.NavigationController`

However, this rootcontroller has a ScrollView and I'm adding subcontrollers (or more precise, the View of this subcontroller) to this ScrollView.

I would now like to access the UINavigationController from inside such subcontroller.
Following properties are all null

```
        this.NavigationController
        this.ParentViewController
        this.PresentedViewController
        this.PresentingViewController
```

It seems in ObjectiveC you can use following code

```
YourAppDelegate *del = (YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[del.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately, i don't know how to map this to C# in MonoTouch.
I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.NavigationController
```

I know I could pass the UINavigationController object to all my classes (parameter in constructor), but that's probably not the cleanest way to go.

Comment: I'm not familiar with monotouch, but you'll have to SET the rootViewController first, not push it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend poupou's answer, here is an example of what I usually do in my `AppDelegate` class:

Add a static property of the `AppDelegate` itself:

```
public static AppDelegate Self { get; private set; }
```

Add my root navigation controller as a property:

```
public UINavigationController MainNavController { get; private set; }
```

In `FinishedLaunching`:

```
Self = this;
window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
this.MainNavController = new UINavigationController(); // pass the nav controller's root controller in the constructor
window.RootViewController = this.MainNavController;
// ..
```

This way, I can access the root view controller from anywhere, like this:

```
AppDelegate.Self.MainNavController.PushViewController(someViewController);
```

... instead of having to write this all the time:

```
AppDelegate myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
myAppDelegate.MainNavController.PushViewController(someViewController);
```

Plus, I can directly access all other `AppDelegate`'s properties I might have.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`UIApplicationDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) does not, itself, define a `navigationController` property.

OTOH `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` returns the instance of your own, *application specific*, `UIApplicationDelegate` - so it's a great place to share stuff (and why it's frequently used).

What *commonly* happens, in ObjectiveC, is that this custom ,`UIApplicationDelegate`-derived, type will implement it's own *application-wise* properties. IOW `YourAppDelegate` will implement a `navigationController` property that can be accessed, anywhere inside the app, by using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`.

You can do something very similar in .NET / C#. Simply add your own properties to your AppDelegate type, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12372352/220643) example. You'll be able to access them like Objective-C (if you like) or more directly (e.g. by making them `public static` properties).

Note that you still have to track and set your properties correctly (just like it needs to be done in Objective-C too).